# 301 Redirects with Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect, routes

I am trying to 301 redirect a url to a new place since the original pages don't exist anymore.  The URL I am trying to run is Guns/Rifles/Heckler_Koch/MP5_A4. I need this to redirect to Guns/Heckler_Koch/. I have tried so many things, but this is the only thing I could come up with and it doesn't work. When I run this it brings me to, manufacturers/items/. Thank you for your help.

```
Router::connect(
    '/Guns/:manufacturer', 
    array('controller' => 'manufacturers', 'action' => 'items'), 

    array('pass' => array('manufacturer'), 'routeClass' => 'GunRoute')
);


Router::redirect(
    '/Guns/Rifles/:manufacturer/*', 
    array('controller' => 'manufacturers', 'action' => 'items'),
    array('pass' => array('manufacturer'), 'status' => '301')        

);
```

Comment: I think what you're missing is that `pass` should be `persist`. Generally speaking you can [debug here](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Routing/Route/RedirectRoute.php#L81-L91) to determine why the url you're generating isn't the url you expect. Note also that 301 is the default redirect status code.

Comment: I can't tell for sure, so I'm not adding this as an answer, but it looks like there could be a bug, As @AD7six said you should use persist, but that still won't work, as the array that is finally passed to `Router::reverse()` will contain a `pass` key filled with whatever `*` matches, and an `url` key which causes the whole thing to fail too (even if it's empty)...

Comment: @ndm well observed/predicted - it's only the pass key that causes a problem e.g. this would work with the routes in the question: `curl -I http://app.dev/Guns/Rifles/Heckler_Koch/`, this won't `curl -I http://app.dev/Guns/Rifles/Heckler_Koch/anything`. Reverse routing is such a clunky feature.

Answer (score 1):

```
Router::connect(
    '/Guns/:manufacturer', 
    array('controller' => 'manufacturers', 'action' => 'items'), 
    array('persist' => array('manufacturer'), 'routeClass' => 'GunRoute')
);
```

Comment: Except, [it does work that way](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#redirect-routing). The pseudo-controller example is not equivalent to what Kevin is trying to do.

Comment: edit it to be an accurate answer - pass -> persist is "the problem".

Comment: So, see comments by @ndm above, it *should* work that way but doesn't/won't. Since it doesn't your previous controller example is actually appropriate. I recommend leaving the route correction since it'll get corrected eventually and will work, but adding any (sufficiently complete) solution you see fit as an alternative. A controller action, a dispatch filter or extending the redirect Route class are the obvious work arounds. You were only missing `'manufacturer` => $this->...['manufacturer']` in your pseudo-redirect example.

Comment: This doesn't work, when I set the connect to persist, it still creates a redirect as /manufacturers/items

Comment: I ended up using @Anubhav original solution since I could not figure out how to do in with the routes.php. You should put back your original answer as that is the only thing that worked for me.